# Вывод своей ячейки в корзине Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

уже неделю мучаюсь не могу не как найти решение! =(
Проблема в следующем - есть интернет магазин на Woocommerce в базе данных я создал новый столбец с названием (saller) и сделал его вывод в карточку товара:

```
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT seller FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = '$id'");
    <span class="sku_wrapper">Продавец: <span class="sku"><?php echo $posts[0]->seller; ?></span></span>
```

теперь мне эту ячейку надо вывести в саму корзину напротив товара.
Помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: перед этим есть строка
global $product, $wpdb; ?
var_dump($posts); - смотрел?

Comment: Да, в масиве нет ячейки которую я добавил(((